# Is it possible to get Click/KeyDown events of contentpage to Masterpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, session-timeout

I am trying to add a SessionTimeOut alert message to a master page. It works on a test page, but when I add it to a master page I am unable to capture the events of the content page that would reset its timer. So it just countdowns just as if a user is idle when in fact they are doing the work on the content pages.

How do I capture the events that are happening on the content page or even any action happening on the current window so I can reset the timer? 
Note: I've tried window.onclick and it doesn't work either

Or maybe if someone knows how to accomplish what I want some other way, I am all ears.

Markup below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>LTH IMS</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <link href="/css/mpIMS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.min.css"/>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body  style="height:500px;" onclick="test2()">
    <form id="frm1"  runat="server">
       
    

            
<div id="container" >
<div id="leftBorder" >
<div id="rightBorder">

    <div id="masthead">
    
        <div id="mastheadright">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FormTop" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
 </div>
      
 <div id="top_nav">
 
 </div>
 <div id="page_content" onclick="SessionTimeOut()">
        
        
        <div id="tabpanel">
          
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1"  runat="server">
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   
        </div>
 </div>
      
 </div>

</div>
</div>

       

       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/jquery.sessionTimeout.js"></script>
    <script>
            function SessionTimeOut() {
            $.sessionTimeout({

                warnAfter: 3000,
                redirAfter: 30000
            });
        }
        function test2() {
            alert('hai');
        }
</script>
       
     
    </form>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use onmousemove on body tag for any mouse event and onkeypress for capturing keyboard events and reset timer in both cases

Comment: Your answer is correct but I am unable to get the buttons in the dialog box to stay enabled now with it in this event. They are enabled until I move the mouse or do an action over the web page. I think I will have to find another route to take for an idle user timeout message on Masterpages. Thank you for your help.